# Can I drill into basement concrete wall to hang a mirror?

Tags: concrete, basement

My basement is unfinished and I have a large concrete wall. Can (should) I drill some small holes in the concrete to hold up a mirror or two?

Are there any serious downsides to drilling into the wall an inch or so?

Comment: Another option is to attach some 2x2 boards to the floor joists so that your 2x2s are flush with your wall.  Then hang your mirror on them.  You will see them extending up from the top of your mirror but that is not so bad.

Comment: @Willk excellent idea - there may be other things to hang later, so adding some framing is much more flexible.  Plus you know that the wood is hung with dynabolts or other suitable concrete anchors, not nails or screws.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem at all - look in your local hardware store for masonry bits and concrete wall anchors.

Comment: This.  Make sure you use a masonry bit to do your drilling, or else you'll have a bad time.

Comment: If you can, borrow a hammer drill, it will take a few seconds to drill each hole.  Dipping the bit in a cup of water every few seconds or so can help keep it cool and speed up the work.

Comment: @JimmyJames comment is good. I go a step further by recommending a rotary hammer over a hammer drill. Any model with an SDS+ shank will probably do. You basically hold the tool in the right direction and the hole virtually drills itself.
A word of warning though: Having used a rotary hammer once, I can say from experience, it is highly addictive and leads to buying a rotary hammer which is a slippery slope to drilling many more holes.

Comment: @Hermann +1 It seems what I last used (rented) was actually a rotary hammer.  I needed to secure posts to a concrete patio.  While I had it, I drilled a couple holes in my foundation to put up a second peg board.  With the rotary hammer, both the patio and the wall were like butter.  I had put up the first peg board with a regular drill w/ masonry bits and if memory serves it took me something like a half-hour per hole, maybe more.

Comment: If you do go with the hammer/rotary, wear a dust mask and eye protection.  Concrete dust can shoot right in your face in a plume.

Comment: @Hermann [obligatory xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/905/)

Answer (score 2):

Done exactly this last week. Have a basement with concrete walls and tiles installed on them.

I used tapcon screws. They came with a proper size concrete drill-bit for the screws.

Started off by marking where screws would go with a pencil. Then drilled very small pilot hole using smallest drill-bit I had. Having it made the tapcon drill-bit stay in place instead of sliding on tiles. Screws went in the hole tightly and hold mounts securely

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if the basement is a prebuilt tub like construction it might void your warranty. I would check with your construction company.

Comment: Huh? Unless this is a brand new home, there wouldn't be a warranty on the basement walls. A typical "Home Warranty" on an older house includes major systems & appliances, not (as far as I know) wall issues. In any case, a few masonry anchors for a mirror should not cause any problems.

Comment: Don't know the country, but here in the Netherlands houses(~10 years or newer) that have a basement are mostly prebuilt and can have a warranty up to 50 years. Drilling in them will void the warranty as it can cause cracks and water to seek in. As I said, best to contact the construction company.

Comment: Wow! Nothing like that in the US, that I know of.

Comment: @yekurtal Consider adding your comment into the answer. As a person who does not live in the Netherlands, I did not understand your answer until reading the comment.

Comment: @manassehkatz More than 50% of the land area of the Netherlands is less than 5 meters (15 feet) above sea level. The level of the water table is important if your house has a basement!

Comment: @Roijan I don't think it is necessary to add it to the comment, I give an example with the best(imo) answer, listing all options would feel like a waste and I don't have the experience or time.